How to "tone-unmap" smartphone photographs to look like digicam shots?


I know the smartphone has the RAW option so that it records both JPEG and DNG files and DNGs can be custom processed in a RAW development program like RawTherapee etc.
But if I have JPEG only photographs, already "Ultra HDR" styled so that they look the preferred way for displaying in social networks in smartphones?
It's possible to achieve a similar effect on digicams shot by applying HDR tonemapping in some programs.
But is it possible to undo it? To make the upper (smartphone) photograph look like the lower (digicam) photograph? (Visible better in the full resolution by clicking the images...)
